# ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have tried rake db:migrate and I can't seem to fix this problem. Anyone know where to begin? I have looked at most of the other pending migration error on StackOverflow and can't seem to find a solution.

Note: Running rails on Windows

After I run rake db:migrate:

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
-- add_index(:conversations, :sender_id)
-- add_index(:conversations, :sender_id)
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.conversations: CREATE  INDEX "index_conversations_on_sender_id" ON "conversations" ("sender_id")
C:/Users/Jason/Documents/GitHub/TruTechEventPlanner/db/migrate/20151118013432_create_chats.rb:13:in `<class:CreateChats>'
C:/Users/Jason/Documents/GitHub/Planner/db/migrate/20151118013432_create_chats.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.conversations
C:/Users/Jason/Documents/GitHub/Planner/db/migrate/20151118013432_create_chats.rb:13:in `<class:CreateChats>'
C:/Users/Jason/Documents/GitHub/Planner/db/migrate/20151118013432_create_chats.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.conversations: CREATE  INDEX "index_conversations_on_sender_id" ON "conversations" ("sender_id")
C:/Users/Jason/Documents/GitHub/Planner/db/migrate/20151118013432_create_chats.rb:13:in `<class:CreateChats>'
C:/Users/Jason/Documents/GitHub/Planner/db/migrate/20151118013432_create_chats.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.conversations
C:/Users/Jason/Documents/GitHub/Planner/db/migrate/20151118013432_create_chats.rb:13:in `<class:CreateChats>'
C:/Users/Jason/Documents/GitHub/Planner/db/migrate/20151118013432_create_chats.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: what happens when you run `rake db:migrate`? Does anything run? Paste the output from that command.

Comment: @Mingsheng, how do you know? Are you related to @user3808788? Because he didn't include to his question that he's using "Windows" OS.

Comment: @joshua.paling I updated this info in the description.

Comment: @OJ1987 I'm not. He's using rails installer. You can see it from his log (earlier) where there's a rails installer path. With his recent update, you can still see 
    C:/Users/Jason/Documents/GitHub/Planner/db/migrate/

Comment: probably something wrong with your migration, @user3808788 .. you need to look at your migrations. "SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.conversations" look in that direction

Comment: As it is clearly saying in error `no such table: main.conversations`, It seems You are trying to create `index` On table called `conversations` but  table didn't exists .